# Expression abstraction

Tags: c#, lambda, expression, abstraction

Is it possible to avoid duplication of this method for each string field in the model I want to check for a match? If `MyModel` is abstracted then obviously the `MyModelField` in the lambda expression is not recognized anymore, so I'm thinking maybe some kind of reflection to access the field by name?

```
private Expression<Func<MyModel, bool>> MatchMyModelFieldByStrategy(SearchItem searchItem)
{
    var searchItemKey = searchItem.Value.ToLower();
    Expression<Func<MyModel, bool>> defaultExp = s => s.MyModelField.ToLower().Contains(searchItemKey);
    switch (searchItem.SearchStrategy)
    {
        case StrStrategy.Contains:
            return defaultExp;
        case StrStrategy.StartsWith:
            return s => s.MyModelField.ToLower().StartsWith(searchItemKey);
        case StrStrategy.EndsWith:
            return s => s.MyModelField.ToLower().EndsWith(searchItemKey);
        case StrStrategy.Equals:
            return s => s.MyModelField.ToLower().Equals(searchItemKey);
    }
    return defaultStrat;
}
```

**EDIT**

I need to call the method for dynamically build predicates to use with Entity Framework queries.

Comment: By the way, upper case is optimal  for string searching and comparing in .Net.

Comment: Do you plan to use result of `MatchMyModelFieldByStrategy` with Entity Framework or LINQ2SQL? If so, code from posted answers will cause entity command compilation exception at run-time, because underlying LINQ providers won't recognize `selector`.

Comment: @Dennis yep I need it to make a dynamic query builder... Do you know any valid alternative to use in combination with EF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you plan to use result of `MatchMyModelFieldByStrategy` with Entity Framework or LINQ2SQL, the `selector` must be an expression instead of delegate, because underlying LINQ providers won't recognize delegate during building entity command text.

Hence, you have to build expression yourself, something like this:

(assuming, that you have similar types:)

```
enum SearchStrategy
{
    Contains,
    StartsWith,
    EndsWith,
    Equals
}

class SearchItem
{
    public SearchStrategy SearchStrategy { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Here's the code, which builds the filtering expression:

```
static class QueryBuilder
{
    private static readonly Lazy<MethodInfo> toLowerMethodInfo;
    private static readonly Dictionary<SearchStrategy, Lazy<MethodInfo>> searchStrategyToMethodInfoMap;

    static QueryBuilder()
    {
        toLowerMethodInfo = new Lazy<MethodInfo>(() => typeof(string).GetMethod("ToLower", new Type[0]));

        searchStrategyToMethodInfoMap = new Dictionary<SearchStrategy, Lazy<MethodInfo>>
        {
            { 
                SearchStrategy.Contains, 
                new Lazy<MethodInfo>(() => typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains", new[] { typeof(string) })) 
            },
            { 
                SearchStrategy.StartsWith, 
                new Lazy<MethodInfo>(() => typeof(string).GetMethod("StartsWith", new[] { typeof(string) })) 
            },
            { 
                SearchStrategy.EndsWith, 
                new Lazy<MethodInfo>(() => typeof(string).GetMethod("EndsWith", new[] { typeof(string) })) 
            },
            { 
                SearchStrategy.Equals, 
                new Lazy<MethodInfo>(() => typeof(string).GetMethod("Equals", new[] { typeof(string) })) 
            },
        };
    }

    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> MatchMyModelFieldByStrategy<T>(SearchItem searchItem, Expression<Func<T, string>> selector)
    {
        // "doe"
        var searchItemKey = searchItem.Value.ToLower();
        // _.Name.ToLower()
        var toLowerCallExpr = Expression.Call(selector.Body, toLowerMethodInfo.Value);
        // a method we shall use for searching
        var searchMethodInfo = searchStrategyToMethodInfoMap[searchItem.SearchStrategy].Value;

        // _ => _.Name.ToLower().SomeSearchMethod("doe")
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(
            Expression.Call(toLowerCallExpr, searchMethodInfo, Expression.Constant(searchItemKey)), 
            selector.Parameters);
    }
}
```

I've added a little laziness to cache reflection results, because for every `MatchMyModelFieldByStrategy` call they'll be the same.

Now the test entity type:

```
class MyEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

... and the sample code:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(QueryBuilder.MatchMyModelFieldByStrategy<MyEntity>(
            new SearchItem { SearchStrategy = SearchStrategy.Contains, Value = "doe" }, _ => _.Name));
        Console.WriteLine(QueryBuilder.MatchMyModelFieldByStrategy<MyEntity>(
            new SearchItem { SearchStrategy = SearchStrategy.StartsWith, Value = "doe" }, _ => _.Name));
        Console.WriteLine(QueryBuilder.MatchMyModelFieldByStrategy<MyEntity>(
            new SearchItem { SearchStrategy = SearchStrategy.EndsWith, Value = "doe" }, _ => _.Name));
        Console.WriteLine(QueryBuilder.MatchMyModelFieldByStrategy<MyEntity>(
            new SearchItem { SearchStrategy = SearchStrategy.Equals, Value = "doe" }, _ => _.Name));

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could provide a property selector function as a parameter. For example:

```
private Expression<Func<MyModel, bool>> MatchMyModelFieldByStrategy(SearchItem searchItem, Func<MyModel, string> propertySelector)
{
    var searchItemKey = searchItem.Value.ToLower();
    Expression<Func<MyModel, bool>> defaultExp = s => propertySelector.Invoke(s).ToLower().Contains(searchItemKey);
    switch (searchItem.SearchStrategy)
    {
        case StrStrategy.Contains:
            return defaultExp;
        case StrStrategy.StartsWith:
            return s => propertySelector.Invoke(s).ToLower().StartsWith(searchItemKey);
        case StrStrategy.EndsWith:
            return s => propertySelector.Invoke(s).ToLower().EndsWith(searchItemKey);
        case StrStrategy.Equals:
            return s => propertySelector.Invoke(s).ToLower().Equals(searchItemKey);
    }
    return defaultStrat;
}
```

Which can be used like this:

```
var matchExpression = MatchMyModelFieldByStrategy(someSearchItem, model => model.MyModelField);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define selector for target field:

```
private Expression<Func<MyModel, bool>> MatchMyModelFieldByStrategy(SearchItem searchItem, Func<MyModel, String> selector)
{
    var searchItemKey = searchItem.Value.ToLower();
    Expression<Func<MyModel, bool>> defaultExp = s =>  selector(s).ToLower().Contains(searchItemKey);
    switch (searchItem.SearchStrategy)
    {
        case StrStrategy.Contains:
            return defaultExp;
        case StrStrategy.StartsWith:
            return s =>  selector(s).ToLower().StartsWith(searchItemKey);
        case StrStrategy.EndsWith:
            return s =>  selector(s).ToLower().EndsWith(searchItemKey);
        case StrStrategy.Equals:
            return s =>  selector(s).ToLower().Equals(searchItemKey);
    }
    return defaultStrat;
}
```

And use it this way:

```
MatchMyModelFieldByStrategy(searchItem, x=>x.MyModelField);
```